# Count matches iteratively with 2 strings indicies

Tags: python, slice

I have 2 strings:

```
string 1 = 'ATCGATCG'
string 2 = 'ATCGATCG'
```

I want to identify which sections of these 2 strings match, starting from the first character and building up. For this I am using the code below which slices 1 character at a time:

```
('A', 'AT', 'ATC', 'ATCG', 'ATCGA', 'ATCGAT', 'ATCGATC', 'ATCGATCG')
```

Is there a method to get it to count the matches between the slices made of string 1 and 2 to see if they match totally print yes, if not print no. I have had trouble identifying how to get it done for each slice.

```
for i in range(0, len(string1)):
    print string1[0:i]

    for i in range(0,len(string2)):
        print string2[0:i]
```

Comment: For total match, why not just: `string1 == string2`

Comment: @sshashank124 In reality each string is ~200 characters long and are only going to match when each is a specific size hence why I need to check if they match at each slice, if it were just for a total match I would use your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just count the matches you need in order to decide whatever you need to decide:

```
s1 = "ATCGATCG"
s2 = "ATCGATCGFOOBAR"

counter = 0

for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2):
  if c1 == c2: 
    counter += 1
  else:
    break

print "String share the longest common prefix of length %d: %s" % (counter, s1[:counter])
```

---

```
String share the longest common prefix of length 8: ATCGATCG
```

Comment: I hope it does. Am I overseeing something?

Comment: That seems perfect, is there a way to identify the position of the start and end character's within the strings?

Comment: c'mon, just put another counter into the loop :)

Comment: @Pavel Well, it prints 0, because you've only accounted for the prefix. Not sure if that meets the needs- I was assuming not because of the nature of DNA and translations and the like.

Comment: @Decency the prefix alone is fine for this purpose as it will be used for pair end read joining and so it only matters if they match from the start.